# Google maps marker appear on native page link

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have a *Google maps* map displaying on a page, the map has a marker on it.

When I click the "Google" link at the bottom left of the map, it opens the map in another tab. This new map does not have the existing marker any longer.

I would like this marker to reappear on the new native Google Maps tab.

This is my existing script:

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false"></script>
<script>
var map,latlng=new google.maps.LatLng(<?php echo $producer_array[0]['latitude']; ?>,<?php   echo $producer_array[0]['longitude']; ?>);
function initialize(){
var mapOptions={
    zoom:12,
    panControl:true,
    panControlOptions:{
      position:google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_RIGHT
    },
    zoomControl:true,
    zoomControlOptions:{
      style:google.maps.ZoomControlStyle.LARGE,
      position: google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_RIGHT
    },
    center:latlng
  };
  map=new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_cv'),mapOptions);
    var marker=new google.maps.Marker({
    position:latlng,
    map: map,
    title:"<?php echo $producer_array[0]['name']; ?>"
});    
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>
```

Is it possible to get this marker to reappear?

Answer (score 1):

To achieve it you must modify the link, what isn't permitted: [**No Modification of Links**](https://developers.google.com/maps/terms?hl=de#section_10_1)

So the answer is: **No**